# A better way to parse time strings

Tags: python, performance

I have been wondering if there is a more concise and faster way to parse a timestamp that could be of 3 formats coming from several locations / log files. The below code is what I have currently, but its a very ugly working version and terribly slow.  Is there a more pythonic and faster way to accomplish this?

```
FORMATS = ["%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"      ,
           "%Y%m%d_%H.%M.%S"        ,
           "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y"]


def _hacktime(self, t):
    # CAUTION: 
    # The nastiest time hack of all TIME
    #
    try:
        t = time.mktime(time.strptime(t, self.FORMATS[0]))
    except:
        try:
            t = time.mktime(time.strptime(t, self.FORMATS[1]))
        except:
            try:
                t = time.mktime(time.strptime(' '.join([t, 
                                                time.strftime('%Y')]),
                                                self.FORMATS[2]))
            except Exception as e:
                print('could not convert time %s: %s' % (t, e))
                t = time.time()   
    return [t, time.ctime(t)]
```

Comment: Why do you append `%Y` to the time string for the third format?  Wouldn't it be easier to simply omit it from the format string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a loop

```
the_time= None
for f in FORMATS:
    try:
        the_time = time.mktime(time.strptime(t, f))
        return the_time # or break 
    except ValueError: 
        continue
if the_time is None:
    raise ValueError( "{0!r} is not a valid time".format(t) )
```

Comment: I'd propose to `break` at the end of the `try` block, and to use an `else` clause to the for loop instead of checking for `None`.

Comment: I accepted this one as it was by far the best.  My final solution was to pass the file extension into the function and route it to the right parser format right away.  Shaved 20% off my processing although strptime() is still the slowest process of my application.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could make a regex to match both of the first two, pulling out the component fields.

I guess that reduces it to two branches, because if the match fails, it must be the third pattern.

If it does match, you might as well populate the `struct_time` directly since you have all the matched fields.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the "-", ":" and " " count for the string before trying to convert them with strptime. Instead of trying and catching exceptions while indenting more for each attempt, use a loop and break out of the loop (or just return) once a conversion works.